# c# xml look for node with / in title

Tags: c#, xml

I've got a WFA running which takes an XML file and "prettifys" it.
what I would like to add now is a check to see if a specific node exists, and if not , display a message.

the XML looks like

```
<message>

<success/>

<bookings>
Some extra nodes I need not look for at this time
</bookings>

</message>
```

what I am (unsuccessfully) trying to do it to look for the existence of

```
    <success/>
```

and if not found, display a message.

The code I have be trying to do this with is

```
            InitializeComponent();
            openFileDialog1.FileName = String.Empty;                    //blank filename
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            XmlNodeList nodeToFind = doc.GetElementsByTagName("success/");

            if (nodeToFind != null)
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText("node found");
            }
```

this did not work, so I tried it by doing a .Count on nodeToFind, and loading the value into a VAR (called Successful) and then amending the If to

```
if (Successful !=0) {
display a message
}
```

but that only comes back with 0 each time.

I am guessing that the it might be the / in the node name.

can anyone help ?
thanks

EDIT:
WORKING CODE now looks like

```
            InitializeComponent();
            openFileDialog1.FileName = String.Empty;                    //blank filename 
             if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {

            richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            XmlNodeList nodeToFind = doc.GetElementsByTagName("success");
            int Successfull = nodeToFind.Count;

            if (Successfull == 0)
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText("node NOT found");
            }
        }
```

thanks @SLaks

Comment: You should use `XDocument`; it's much easier.

Comment: I'm learning that the hard way :-). Next lesson involving XML, I will :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a self-closing tag (equivalent to `<success></success>`).

The `/` is not part of the name.

Comment: THANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOU . Ive been battleing with this all day. Noob that I am..